# How to use CASE statement with string?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, case

I have a column (Name) having values (John,Liza,Ali,Elizabeth). I want to create a column (Eligible ) that will show 'NO' only to a specific row and display 'YES' to remaining rows.Is there anything like case column when not expression then expression ?

```
SELECT NAME,
case NAME when 'JOHN' then 'YES' end eligible
FROM TABLE

Expected :
NAME          |   Eligible 
JOHN                NO     
ALI                 YES
ELIZABETH           YES
LIZA                YES
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select name,
       case 
           when name = 'JOHN' then 'NO'
           else 'YES'
       end eligible 
from table
```

Comment: Thank you. My bad I forgot about the 'else'